# How can redirect based on role after authentication with spring security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, spring-security

I use spring security, spring, hibernate and jsf authentication work correctly but it always redirects me to the page home.jsf

I want to manage the access of users after authentication

I want to manage the access of users after authentication

if authority = ROLE_ADMIN redirect ves homeadmin.jsf

if authority = ROLE_RH redirect ves homerh.jsf

if authority = ROLE_EXCUTIVE redirect ves homeex.jsf

if authority = ROLE_MANAGER redirect ves homem.jsf

if authority = ROLE_GP redirect ves homegp.jsf

The autority field in the Collaborateur table

the Colaborateur Class is

```
private Integer idColaborateur;
    private Rolecol rolecol;
    private String matriculeColaborateur;
    private String nomColaborateur;
    private String prenomColaborateur;
    private String mailColaborateur;
    private String pwdColaboratuer;
    private String loginColaborateur;

    private String adresseColaborateur;
    private Boolean flgSuspendu;
    private Set<HistoriqueNoteObjctif> historiqueNoteObjctifs = new HashSet<HistoriqueNoteObjctif>(
            0);
    private Set<Note> notes = new HashSet<Note>(0);
    private Set<NoteObjectifs> noteObjectifses = new HashSet<NoteObjectifs>(0);
    private Set<CompagneDevaluation> compagneDevaluations = new HashSet<CompagneDevaluation>(
            0);
    private Set<ColaborateurHierarchique> colaborateurHierarchiques = new HashSet<ColaborateurHierarchique>(
            0);
    private String authority;
  //getter and seter
```

Datasource configuration is in the file applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/modulevsql" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="0" />
        <property name="maxAdministrativeTaskTime" value="0" />
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="0" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="0" />
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="0" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="0" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
    </bean>
```

the User Class is

```
public class User implements UserDetails {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private Colaborateur user;

    public void setUser(Colaborateur user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User(String name) {
        FacesContext fc=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();      
        UserBean userBean=(UserBean) fc.getApplication().createValueBinding("#{UserBean}").getValue(fc);

        userBean.chargerUtilisateur(name);
        user = userBean.getUtilisateur();


        System.err.println("USERS    >>> "+user);


        PasswordSupport pswdSupport = new PasswordSupport();

        if (user!=null){

            System.out.println("User.getLogin() :"+user.getLoginColaborateur());
            System.out.println("user.getPwd() :"+user.getPwdColaboratuer());
            this.name=user.getMatriculeColaborateur();
            this.password=user.getPwdColaboratuer();
            System.err.println(pswdSupport.getMD5Hash("1"));
        }
    }


    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();



        System.out.println("GrantedAuthorityImpl  1");
        System.out.println("GrantedAuthorityImpl  2");
        System.out.println("GrantedAuthorityImpl  3");
        System.out.println("GrantedAuthorityImpl  4");

        grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_VISITEUR"));


        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
           //getter and setter
```

and this is applicationContext-security.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

      <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
      </global-method-security>


      <http pattern="/modules/members/**" access-denied-page="/modules/members/accessDenied.jsf" authentication-manager-ref="MembersAuthenticationManager">

              <intercept-url pattern="/modules/members/secure/**" access="ROLE_VISITEUR" /> 
            <intercept-url pattern="/modules/members/secure/homeadmin.jsf" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

            <form-login login-page="/modules/members/login.jsf"
                   default-target-url="/modules/members/secure/home.jsf" 
                  login-processing-url="/modules/members/j_spring_security_check"
                  authentication-failure-url="/modules/members/login.jsf" /> 
            <logout logout-url="/modules/members/secure/logout"
                  logout-success-url="/modules/members/login.jsf" delete-cookies="true" />

      </http>


      <authentication-manager alias="MembersAuthenticationManager">
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="securityManager">
                  <password-encoder hash="md5" />
            </authentication-provider>
      </authentication-manager>
      <beans:bean id="securityManager" class="tn.com.security.SecurityManager" />

</beans:beans>
```

and this is MyAuthSuccessHandler class

```
@Component
public class MyAuthSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    //    @Autowired
    //    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //        // changeLastLoginTime(username)
        // userService.changeLastLoginTime(authentication.getName());

        setDefaultTargetUrl("/modules/members/secure/home.jsf");

        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }


    protected boolean hasRole(String role) {
        // get security context from thread local
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        if (context == null)
            return false;

        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null)
            return false;

        for (GrantedAuthority auth : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
            if (role.equals(auth.getAuthority()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

how I can update the class MyAuthSuccessHandler ,USer and applicationContext.xml file
to manage the access of users after authentication

if authority = ROLE_ADMIN redirect ves homeadmin.jsf

if authority = ROLE_RH redirect ves homerh.jsf

if authority = ROLE_EXCUTIVE redirect ves homeex.jsf

if authority = ROLE_MANAGER redirect ves homem.jsf

if authority = ROLE_GP redirect ves homegp.jsf

this is UserBean class

```
@Component("UserBean")
@Scope("session")
public final class UserBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private Colaborateurservice colaborateurservice;

    private Colaborateur utilisateur;

    public UserBean() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initiate() {

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public void testBean() {
        System.out.println("testBean");

    }

    public void chargerParametreGlob() {

        try {

            System.out.println("chargerParametreGlob  ");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void chargerUtilisateur(String login) {
        System.out.println(login);
        try {

            utilisateur = new Colaborateur();
            List<Colaborateur> list = colaborateurservice
                    .findByMatriculeColaborateurlo(login);

            System.out.println(list);

            if (list.size() > 0) {

                this.utilisateur = (Colaborateur) list.get(0);
                System.out.println("utilisateur.getLogin() :"
                        + utilisateur.getMatriculeColaborateur());

                System.out.println("utilisateur.getPwd() :"
                        + utilisateur.getLoginColaborateur().length());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public String logout() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                .getSession(true);
        if (session == null) {
            return "logout";
        } else {
            session.invalidate();
            return "logout";
        }
    }

    public void setUtilisateur(Colaborateur utilisateur) {
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
    }

    public Colaborateur getUtilisateur() {
        return utilisateur;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are extending out an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, its not really going to help you by calling `super.onAuthenticationSuccess()`.

Try the following:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult){
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> auths = authResult.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority authorities : auths)
        {
            if (authorities.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")){
                response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL("homeadmin.jsf");
            }
            else if(authorities.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_RH")){
                response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL("homerh.jsf");
        .  .  .
           //Repeat pattern until all roles checked
        }
```

and then change your config to:

```
<http pattern="/modules/members/**" 
    <!-- Pass in a reference to your customAuthenticationSuccessHandler -->
    authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    access-denied-page="/modules/members/accessDenied.jsf" 
    authentication-manager-ref="MembersAuthenticationManager">

        <intercept-url pattern="/modules/members/secure/**" access="ROLE_VISITEUR" /> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/modules/members/secure/homeadmin.jsf" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <form-login login-page="/modules/members/login.jsf"
              default-target-url="/modules/members/secure/home.jsf" 
              login-processing-url="/modules/members/j_spring_security_check"
              authentication-failure-url="/modules/members/login.jsf" /> 
        <logout logout-url="/modules/members/secure/logout"
              logout-success-url="/modules/members/login.jsf" delete-cookies="true" />

  </http>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"  
      class="foo.bar.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

Extending out `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is almost pointless, because you can't set where you want the superclass to send you to. You may as well implement the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` interface and pass your custom implementation into Spring Security.

Also because you are implementing an interface, you can autowire any of your service classes in.

I've used this method myself and it works fine, assuming that each user has only 1 role. If a user has more than one role, they will be redirected to the first role found. You may wish to order your if statements so that the user gets sent to the area with the least responsibility.

Comment: thank you for your help in trying to implement your code, but there's an exception The type Collection is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends GrantedAuthority>I don't know what it is because it is my first time working with spring security