# How to override default spring security XML configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have a internal framework which does the login authentication process for our application using spring security 3.1.4
Here is a part of a security-applicationContext.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd"> 
//some other beans....
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        request-matcher-ref="localAuthRequestMatcher">
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN_PERMISSION')" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/system/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN_PERMISSION')" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/enduser/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/changePassword.do" access="isAuthenticated()"/>      
  <intercept-url pattern="/index.do" access="isAnonymous()" />
  <custom-filter after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="welcomePageRedirectFilter" />
  <custom-filter before="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="internalAuthenticationFilter" />
  <form-login login-page="/index.do" authentication-failure-handler-ref="DCAuthenticationFailureHandler" authentication-success-handler-ref="DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
  <http-basic />
  <anonymous />      
  <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="customSessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />  
  <logout success-handler-ref="localLogoutSuccessHandler" />       
</http> 
</beans:beans>
```

We reference this security-applicationContext.xml configuration in our applicationContext as below

```
<import resource="classpath:/security-applicationContext.xml" />
```

I need to extend the functionality of DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler so I created a new class CPAuthenticationSuccessHandler by extending DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler.

How do i configure my CPAuthenticationSuccessHandler as authentication-success-handler to override the functionality of DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler without touching the security-applicationContext.xml. I really appreciate someone's help on this

I created CPAuthenticationHandler as below

```
@Component
@Primary
public class CPAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
 @Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    new DefaultRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response,
            this.onAuthenticationSuccessUrl(request, response, authentication));
}

    @Override
    public String onAuthenticationSuccessUrl(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
.......
}
```

But CPAuthenticationSuccessHandler is not invoked, i have a breakpoint in both the handlers but control is always going to DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677717/how-can-redirect-based-on-role-after-authentication-with-spring-security/23692631#23692631) for an example of how to wire in a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` into your security context.

However, in your case, instead of implementing `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, you want to extend `DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and call `super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication)` on the last line of your `CPAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Something like this:

```
public class CPAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DCAuthenticationSuccessHandler{
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication){
        /* Do anything that you want to do here. Any changes to the HttpServletResponse
         * will be overwritten when you call super. So when you call super will
         * depend on what logic you want to implement.
         */

        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

If there is anything you don't understand, let me know

Comment: please check my latest edit, I made chanegs as u suggested but its not working